# How to intent KEY_URL data the other activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

How to intent KEY_URL data the WV activity ?

I hope I could tell I. Thank you in advance for your help.

This is my intent button

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.haftalikizle);
                button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                         Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VW.class);
                         i.putExtra("link",(KEY_URL).toString());
                         startActivity(i);
                     }});
```

This my full code, but not work. ideas, thoughts, or you can edit your.

```
public class haftalik extends ListActivity {
static final String URL = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/qd33n0zxcmrnsf2/haftalik.xml";
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item";
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_BILGI = "bilgi";
static final String KEY_URL = "url";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

public WebView tarayici;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
ConnectivityManager connectivity = null;
ListView lv;
haftalik2 adapter;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> catalogList;
Button button;


//@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.haftalik_main);

    if(isConn())
    {

    catalogList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    new LoadCatalog().execute();
    }

    else
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dene.class);
        startActivity(i);
        this.finish();
}
}

class LoadCatalog extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>   {

        @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
             super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(haftalik.this);
//                pDialog.setMessage("");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
         }

         protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
             XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
             String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
                Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
                // looping through all song nodes &lt;song&gt;
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key =&gt; value

                    map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                    map.put(KEY_BILGI, parser.getValue(e, KEY_BILGI));
                    map.put(KEY_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_URL));
                    map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    catalogList.add(map);
                }
                return null;
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
             // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                // updating UI from Background Thread
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        lv=getListView();
                         adapter=new haftalik2(haftalik.this, catalogList);
                         lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                         pDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.haftalikizle);
                button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                         Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VW.class);
                         i.putExtra("link",(KEY_URL).toString());
                         startActivity(i);
                     }});  
         }
}
    public boolean isConn(){
        connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if(connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo()!=null){
            if(connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
 }
```

and my adapter class

```
public class haftalik2 extends BaseAdapter {

    String url=null;
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public haftalik2(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.haftalik, null);

        TextView bilgi = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.bilgi);
        //TextView url = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.url); 
        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.poster); 

        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);


        bilgi.setText(song.get(haftalik.KEY_BILGI));
       //url.setText(song.get(haftalik.KEY_URL));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(haftalik.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are having problem when passing the intent extra?

Comment: could you please explain a bit more?